# how to read esp with gdb

Tags: debugging, memory, assembly, gdb

```
   0x0804889a <+361>:   mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x0804889e <+365>:   movl   $0x2b,0x8(%esp)
   0x080488a6 <+373>:   movl   $0x1,0x4(%esp)
   0x080488ae <+381>:   movl   $0x8048ab0,(%esp)
```

program is adding data to %esp (the last line is a string from memory that i can probe)

i'm currently breaking at the last line of the above. and `info registers` shows

```
esp            0xffffd704       0xffffd704
```

when i try to `display` it i get

```
$esp = (void *) 0xffffd704
```

if i try to dump it

```
(gdb) dump memory mem2 0xffffd704 0xffffffff
Cannot access memory at address 0xffffd704

(gdb) info mem
Using user-defined memory regions.
There are no memory regions defined.
```

how can i see the full value of esp?

Comment: The `0xffffd704` is in kernel space of the progress, and `gdb` can't dump kernel space. You should use `kgtp` to help you. From the value of the `ebp`, I think the stack space is corrupted by overflow.

Comment: @NanXiao if you run 32 bit program under 64 bit linux, you will get the stack in that range, and that is normally accessible user space. However, `gdb` indeed fails to dump that memory, as indicated in the question.

Comment: that is indeed running in 64bit linux. but the program author claimed to have compiled it for 64bit as well. even though i can only run it on gdb if arch===i386.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is misleading. According to my tests, `gdb` prints that if any byte in the range is inaccessible. As such, the problem is with the end address. You can get the stack top from `/proc/<pid>/maps`, for example for my test program I got:

```
$ grep stack /proc/8277/maps
fffdd000-ffffe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [stack]
```

`gdb` is able to dump that memory range without problems.

Of course if you only want to read particular values of interest, you can use the `x` (*examine*) command.